# Coveo cloud indexing too slow

Tags: coveo

Using Coveo cloud (Coveo for Sitecore 4.0.450.0), the rebuilding of just coveo_web and coveo_master indexes takes too long. Once all items are added, the Indexing Manager dialog is stuck for over an hour spinning.

This is the status I see on the index in coveo cloud:

```
Performing rebuild
 Started an hour ago - No items processed
```

This is what is see in Indexing manager:

```
Rebuilding...
Job running: Index_Update_IndexName=Coveo_master_index
[Items Added to Index: 6278]

Job running: Index_Update_IndexName=Coveo_web_index
[Items Added to Index: 6277]
```

I've already opened up ports as described here: https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/cloud/granting_the_coveo_cloud_platform_access_to_your_on-premises_ces_index.htm

Comment: Could you check if there are any errors in the Sitecore logs? Were they the first indexing operation?

Comment: Also, could you check the Coveo Diagnostic Page and edit your question with any error you find there. Thanks.

Comment: no errors in log or in diagnostic page

Comment: You should be able to see some logs regarding the indexing process, starting with `[Rebuilding source "YOUR COVEO SOURCE"]`, could you check at which step the indexing takes a long time? (more information can be found here: https://developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Understanding+the+Rebuild+Process)

Comment: Looks like its Committed documents counter. Which is taking too long to commit. It is doing at an approximate rate of 10/sec. And I have over 7k items to commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Committed Documents` step in Coveo for Sitecore (referred to as `Waiting for documents to be searchable...` in the documentation) is simply querying the index to notify you when your documents are *really* accessible from a search page. 10/sec with 7k documents looks OK to me, but it looks like this step is not the one that is taking all of that "over an hour" time.

I suspect the `Deleted Documents` step to be the culprit since it is usually the longest part in the indexing *validation* process. It validates that the old documents are deleted from the index.

If you don't mind waiting for that visual feedback, you can simply close the dialog and your documents will be available at a later time.

This slowest part could not be improved before because of technical issues, though the next Coveo for Sitecore version will contain such improvement to the process and should handle better the case you are currently experiencing.

You could also try to rebuild one index at a time instead, or re-index small parts of the tree, it can only help :)